# Highchart Plugin JQuery xAxis is undefined

Tags: jquery, angular, highcharts

I am in Angular using JQuery to remove the grid lines from the yAxis and add them to the xAxis instead from the Highcharts plugin. In using the below code, it works perfectly for the first function referencing the yAxis, but the exact same code referencing the xAxis gives me a result that I "Cannot set property 'gridLineWidth' of undefined". What am I missing?

```
ngOnInit() {
        $('table.return')
            .bind('highchartTable.beforeRender', function (event, highChartConfig) {
                $.each(highChartConfig.yAxis, function (index, value) {
                    value.labels.rotation = value.labels.rotation || -45;
                    value.gridLineWidth = 0;
                });
                $.each(highChartConfig.xAxis, function (index, value) {
                    value.gridLineWidth = 1;
                });
}
```

Comment: Why you don't simply use the Highcharts API ?

Comment: Simply using the Highcharts API gives me an error as well... perhaps because I'm using the plugin? "ERROR ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined"

Comment: Could you provide me with minimal working example of your app, which shows the problem? What is the `highChartConfig`? It's a Chart object or only the configuration which you passed to Highcharts in order to create the chart?